# Javascript numbers - split/slice Prime

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to Javascript and trying to solve a simple problem now for more than two weeks and still not getting it(please help).

TASK ::::

1. Read a 4 digit Number e.g. 5678
2. Write a function
3. Split/separate the numbers and than build (5678, 567, 56, 5), than check if the numbers(5678, 567, 56, 5) are Prime numbers.
4. Give in Console/Result if 5678 a prime number or not, 567 a prime number or not and so on.
5. Check  "if all numbers are Prime" than show result "All prime" if not show result "Not all prime".

Trying to solve the problem with (if else) but not really getting it, because i know very less about Javascript (arrays, string, split, slice) yet.
please help me understand. Thanks.

```
var a =  123456789;
    var b = a.toString().length;  //<<--->> ANTWORT: 9
    document.write('ANTWORT: ',a );
    for (i=0; i<b; i++) {
        var x = a.toString().slice(0, -i);
        document.write(x, ",");
    }
    
    function isPrime{
    for(var i = 2; i < a; i++);
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
    return num > 1;
    }
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) - please may you add a [mcve] of your effort so far?

Comment: If you are completely new to JavaScript, why not start with simpler tasks, like Hello World, Guess the number, Hangman, ...etc until you can deal with this?

Comment: what part are you stuck on? Surly it cant be `1.`

Comment: is it supposed to generate every possible combination of 5678, or just remove one number from off the end every time, like in your example?

Comment: Hi ShanerM13 and others it is suppose to remove the last number every time. I understand that i will have to write a function isPrime to call later on in the loop to check if a number is prime or not.

<script> 
        var a =  123456789;
        var b = a.toString().length;  //<<--->> ANTWORT: 9
        //var m = b.slice(-1);
        document.write('ANTWORT: ',a );
        for (i=0; i<b; i++) {
            var x = a.toString().slice(0, -i);

            document.write(x, ",");
            
        }
        
    </script>

Comment: So I wrote an answer that will do exactly what you want, for the most part. It parses the number, splits it accordingly, and puts the values of the numbers in an array, and likewise for the prime number checks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//integer is a string at the moment
integer = prompt("Enter a integer: ");
//initialize array for dictionary
dictArray = [];
stuff = document.getElementById("stuff");

//loop through all values of the string
for (var i = integer.length; i > 0; i--)
{
    //take a substring from 0 to the ith char and turn it into an int
    num = parseInt(integer.substring(0, i));
    //add a dictionary to the array the tells what the number is
    //and if it was prime or not as a bool
    dictArray.push({"num": num, "prime": isprime(num)});
    (dictArray[integer.length - i]["prime"]) ? stuff.innerHTML += "<br>" + num + " is prime." : stuff.innerHTML += "<br>" + num + " is not prime.";
}

function isprime(num)
{

  if (num <= 3) return num >= 1;
  
  if ((num % 2 === 0) || (num % 3 === 0)) return false;
  
  let count = 5;
  
  while (Math.pow(count, 2) <= num) {
    if (num % count === 0 || num % (count + 2) === 0) return false;
    
    count += 6;
  }
  
  return true;
}

//print the array

(dictArray.find(x => !x.prime) == undefined) ? stuff.innerHTML += "<br>All prime!" : stuff.innerHTML += "<br>Not all prime!";

//console.log(dictArray);
```

```html
<div id="stuff">
</div>
```

Comment: The `isprime` func can be shortened to `return (num % 2 == 0);`. Should even work without brackets, but I like brackets ^^

Comment: `num % 2 == 0` is not a valid prime check at all, though, since there's plenty of odd numbers that aren't prime (9, 15, 21 etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think i have not been able to express the problem in right way. e.g. we take a number, lets say 1234.
Now we check if 1234 is prime or not -- True / False 
Print the result out "1234 is not prime"

Now we want to remove the last 123(4) from it, that gives us 123 as a number.
Now we check if 123 is prime or not -- True / False 
Print the result out "123 is prime"

Now we want to remove the last 12(3) from it, that gives us 12 as a number.
Now we check if 12 is prime or not -- True / False 
Print the result out "12 is prime"

Comment: @Psychemaster, the author of the problem is going to write the function to do prime checking. I love prime numbers, like any other math fanatic.

Comment: @higgsboson, did you not say you are going to write a isprime() function?

Comment: Now we want to remove the last 1(2) from it, that gives us 1 as a number.
Now we check if 1 is prime or not -- True / False 
Print the result out "1 is prime"

After all this we want to check and Print the result --> if all numbers are prime or not

Comment: @Psychemaster, seeing that the requirements for the problem have changed, I found a primality test from wikipedia and threw it into the isprime() function. I don't believe the primality test is for me to have to technically write.

Comment: Well yes actually. I want to check the numbers if they are prime or not? but i have to write a function for that i think.

Comment: @higgsboson, as per your comment: "I understand that i will have to write a function isPrime to call later on in the loop to check if a number is prime or not."

Comment: yes exactly ShanerM13, the code you have  written does the right thing! but what we need further is to add code to check, if all results are prime or not.

Comment: `dictArray.find(x => !x.prime) == undefined` should return true if all values are prime, using this example.

Comment: @Psychemaster, thanks. That's a nice tool. Out for lunch now.

Comment: @ShanerM13 and Psychemaster thanks a lot to both.

Comment: @higgsboson, you're welcome. If this was the answer you were looking for, please leave an upvote.

Comment: @Psychemaster and ShanerM can you please read the task once again please. Task: 

Read 4 Numbers e.g. 6789.

Write a Function primeTest(), separate the row 6789 and than build (6789,678,67,6), check if these are Prime numbers. Print the results out(returned from Function primeTest --> Prime yes/No). Print than the final result:: if all 4 numbers(6789,678,67,6) are prime Numbers than "All primes" and if not than "Not all Primes" Sorry fo ShanerM13 , when i add document.write(dictArray); at the end of the code, I am not getting the desired result. I am missing something in the code above.

Comment: @higgsboson Which task do I fail? I just reread - do I not satisfy all?

Comment: @higgsboson, my bad. I found it. Added a solution. Please check.

Comment: @ShanerM13 the Solution you have posted is workin perfectlyy fine in console.log! but I am not able to make it work in document.write(on a website). I thought if a code works with console.log in console than it should be working with document.write on a website. Am i missing here something

Comment: @higgsboson https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write for document.write()... it clears the document... what you should do is something like what I am about to add to the code. You need to include the id `stuff` on some html tag... for example: `<body id="stuff"></body>` or instead of body, a `div` tag. `stuff` is a user generated name... it could be something else, but you need to change the javascript code to reflect the name change.

Comment: @ShanerM13 THANKS a million times dear for your help, I understand it much better now. And it is working.

Comment: sweet, please be sure to leave an upvote or mark it as the accepted answer. that'd be appreciated. glad I could help!